# What algorithm does Blender use to simulate the interaction between fluid and object?

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

For research purpose, I need to implement the interaction between fluid and object. And I found that Blender is able to do this interaction (as shown in the picture).

My questions are:

1. What algorithm does Blender use to implement this interaction?
2. Can I add some additional force terms into the equations of this interaction in Blender, so I can change the behaviour of the fluid? (Not just change the parameters in the panels, but add some new force terms)

[image]

Comment: Blender's fluid sim is made to look realistic, not to be realistic. You are far better off using a different program than blender.

Comment: @Ezra Since I have tried almost a month, but my program didn't work. Then I found Blender's, and I think it may be a good start point for me.

Comment: Blender is open source

Comment: I think it's 'simple' bullet physics

Comment: @lemon Yes, I know that. And I'm searching for the fluid part and the interaction part in its source code. But I also want to know what algorithm or which papers does Blender refer to. BTW, could you tell me where is the fluid and interaction part if you know?

Comment: @BertVdB That will be another question I want to ask: How to integrate fluid motion into Bullet Physics? Should I ask this question in a new post?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:DK/2.4/Manual/Physics/Fluids, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_Boltzmann_methods.. this is probably around simulation_object.cpp in the source code

Comment: Hi, Maybe this addon can be useful for you:  http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/  This is molecular script by PyroEvil. And source code here: https://github.com/Pyroevil/Blender-Molecular-Script

Comment: @lemon Thank you very much! The code about LBM is there. According to Blender's manual, it also has SPH solver for Navier-Stokes equations, and I also want to find those source codes. Do you have any idea where they are?

Comment: @Shubol3D Cool addon! Thank you very much! That's a great reference!

Comment: SPH, probably in particle_system.c... (I have just grep the sources...)

Comment: @lemon I can't believe that I forgot to use grep! And yes, the SPH is in particle_system.c! And both the paper that Blender refers to, and the collision detection and response code are in this file. Thank you very much! And can you provide your comments as an answer, so I can finish this thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wanted information were found by both googling the keywords "blender fluid simulation" which leads to this [page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Physics/Fluid) of the 2.4 documentation and some grep in the source code of Blender.

In this doc page, you can see a "technical details" chapter which indicates three algorithms :

- Lattice Boltzmann Method (LBM)
- Navier-Stokes (NS)
- Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics (SPH). SPH seems to be approximations to the Lagrangian formulation of the Navier-Stokes equations

From that, I did only grep in the Visual Studio solution (don't imagine a minute I know anything more about all that...). For instance :

[image]

To summarize :

- LBM is in simulation_object.cpp
- SPH is in particle_system.c